# Print queue tracking

Tags: printing, print-server

I would like to track printing to network printers.  Specifically, how many **color** prints each user is printing to specific Windows server print queues.  I've found a product that does something similar by Ricoh called PCS Director but it is overkill.  Does anybody know of a simple product that does something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PaperCut provide a free print logging solution, as well as a free 5-user license for small businesses of PaperCut NG.
http://www.papercut.com/products/free_software/

Answer (score 1):

Any time I've had to produce this kind of information, we've gotten a printer that tracks that data on its own, rather than installing something to interact with the print server queue.  Just on the off chance that buying the new printer(s) is an option.  ;)

There are apps like this - http://www.amtsoft.com/printmanager/ but I'm not sure I've seen one that distinguishes between B/W & color.  You'd have to designate color printers for color jobs only (or as counting toward your color quota/billing/etc)